# parameterized insert/update in sql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I am trying to insert into a db that I have, and I'd like to do so through parameters. I am connecting to a postgres db using java.

I can connect to the db just fine. I know that because I have various operations that I am using that are already working were I can see, and update existing rows in my db. I am having trouble with INSERT.

I have the following:

```
private String _update_rentals = "INSERT into rentals (cid, mid) values (?,?)"; 
private PreparedStatement _update_rentals_statement; 

private String _update_movie_status = "UPDATE Movie SET checkedout = true WHERE mid = ?";
private PreparedStatement _update_movie_status_statement;
```

And I initialize them:

```
_update_movie_status_statement = _customer_db.prepareStatement(_update_movie_status); 
        _update_rentals_statement = _customer_db.prepareStatement(_update_rentals);
```

And

```
while (movieAvail.next()){
            System.out.println(movieAvail.getBoolean(1));
            if (movieAvail.getBoolean(1) == false){
                //Do chekcout

                _update_rentals_statement.clearParameters();
                _update_rentals_statement.setInt(1, cid);
                _update_rentals_statement.setInt(2, mid);
                _update_rentals_statement.executeQuery(); 

                _update_movie_status_statement.clearParameters();
                _update_movie_status_statement.setInt(1, mid);
                _update_movie_status_statement.executeQuery(); 


                System.out.println("Enjoy your movie!"); 
            } 
}
```

I am getting an error with both of the executeQuery() calls. For some reason I am getting the following error with both:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
```

I looked at other posts, and I believed that I was following syntax for both insert/ update correctly, so maybe I am overlooking some aspect of this.

This is all part of a larger code base, so I did not want to include the methods these pieces of code are in. But these are the isolated instances which play a part with this code.

Comment: I'm assuming you actually created the PreparedStatement instances?

Comment: Yes, Sorry I will make that clearer in the description.

Comment: you need to use `executeUpdate()` not `executeQuery()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when you execute a `query`, you are willing to retrieve some kind of information from the database. This is usually the case when you are executing `SELECT` queries. However, with `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements, you are not *querying* the database, you are simply executing an update or inserting new rows. In the documentation of `PreparedStatement` you can see in which cases an exception is being thrown when you try to call `executeQuery`:

> Throws: SQLException - if a database access error occurs; this method
>   is called on a closed PreparedStatement or the SQL statement does not
>   return a ResultSet object

So in your case the problem is that your statements do not return a `ResultSet`. You should use `execute` or `executeUpdate` instead. The former simply executes the update, while the latter does the same, but also returns the number of affected rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is that you are calling executeQuery(), which expects a result to be returned, but Insert/Update are not queries and don't return a result.  Try just calling execute().

Comment: This was exactly it. Thank you!